# breaks are not unique when used bin.var function in R

Tags: r

I have this portion of dataframe (dfPancan2):

```
  -0.00616222 3.0501945 4.135684 
  -0.00616222 1.6888945 2.902784
  -0.00616222 1.6214945 2.621384
  -0.00616222 1.5550945 2.315284
  -0.00616222 1.4541945 2.286884
  -0.00616222 1.2254945 2.155184
  -0.00616222 1.2177945 2.068584
  -0.00616222 1.2092945 1.958784
... ... ...
```

when I used this function:

```
dfPancan2$variable <-
  with(dfPancan2,
       bin.var(
         dfPancan2[c(1:nrow(dfPancan2)), 1],
         bins = 3,
         method = 'proportions',
         labels = c('D', 'M', 'UP')
       ))
```

it would get the following dataframe:

```
  -0.00616222 3.0501945 4.135684 UP
  -0.00616222 1.6888945 2.902784 UP
  -0.00616222 1.6214945 2.621384 UP
  -0.00616222 1.5550945 2.315284 M
  -0.00616222 1.4541945 2.286884 M
  -0.00616222 1.2254945 2.155184 D
  -0.00616222 1.2177945 2.068584 D
  -0.00616222 1.2092945 1.958784 D
... ... ...
```

But it got an error message:

```
Error in cut.default(x, quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/bins), na.rm = TRUE),  : 
  the 'breaks' are not distinct
```

the error I guess is due to the constancy of the first column

Any solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. The problem is due to the constancy of the first column.
You cannot split the range of a constant numeric variable into bins of equal width or equal frequency. 
If you cut the second column, your code works fine:

```
dfPancan2 <- as.data.frame(read.table(text="
  -0.00616222 3.0501945 4.135684 
  -0.00616222 1.6888945 2.902784
  -0.00616222 1.6214945 2.621384
  -0.00616222 1.5550945 2.315284
  -0.00616222 1.4541945 2.286884
  -0.00616222 1.2254945 2.155184
  -0.00616222 1.2177945 2.068584
  -0.00616222 1.2092945 1.958784
"))

library(Rcmdr)
dfPancan2$variable <-
  bin.var(dfPancan2[, 2], bins = 3,
         method = 'proportions',
         labels = c('D', 'M', 'UP'))

dfPancan2
```

The output is:

```
           V1       V2       V3 variable
1 -0.00616222 3.050194 4.135684       UP
2 -0.00616222 1.688894 2.902784       UP
3 -0.00616222 1.621495 2.621384       UP
4 -0.00616222 1.555095 2.315284        M
5 -0.00616222 1.454195 2.286884        M
6 -0.00616222 1.225494 2.155184        D
7 -0.00616222 1.217794 2.068584        D
8 -0.00616222 1.209294 1.958784        D
```

Comment: OK, I understand, but I think it is not a good solution, because I don't know if the first column is constant or the 100th column is constant.

Comment: it is a good idea, but it doesn't work. dfPancan2 have a 473 observer, if I try to execute `length(unique(dfPancan2[,2]))` the output is 169, but I get the same error message as before.

Comment: I like your idea, but 169 is not a high number of different values because `bin.var` gives me the same error message as before. But using this instruction `which.max(apply(dfPancan2, 2, function(x)length(unique(x))))[[1]]` I get the column index that contain of the highest number of different values, and `bin.var` runs correctly. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I've alredy tested the function with column that have a 169 number of different values and the function keeps giving error!

Comment: @giupardeb I applied `bin.var` on your columns and it works! No error messages. Give me more details about what are you doing. In my opinion you are doing something wrong...